# MongoDB - interpret particular explain output

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am using MongoDB version 2.4.8.

```
[test] 2014-03-25 14:42:13.0 >>> db.users.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "username" : 1,
                        "age" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "username_1_age_1"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "age" : 1,
                        "username" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "name" : "age_1_username_1"
        }
]
[test] 2014-03-25 14:44:36.550 >>>

[test] 2014-03-25 14:33:12.945 >>> db.users.find({"age" : 14, "username" : /.*/}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor age_1_username_1 multi",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 16850,
        "nscannedObjects" : 16850,
        "nscanned" : 16850,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 16850,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 16850,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 86,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "age" : [
                        [
                                14,
                                14
                        ]
                ],
                "username" : [
                        [
                                "",
                                {

                                }
                        ],
                        [
                                /.*/,
                                /.*/
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "server01:27017"
}
```

What does the explain output mean in its `username` part?

```
            "username" : [
                    [
                            "",
                            {

                            }
                    ],
                    [
                            /.*/,
                            /.*/
                    ]
            ]
```

I have troubles understanding this part no
matter if I look at it formally and informally.

Comment: Not really an answer, but why are you querying for a "match everything" regexp? Sounds like you could use `$exists` or `$type` to query for "has a username" or "has a username that's a string".

Comment: @Avish It is just an example I found in a book.

Comment: pretty terrible example - are you sure this wasn't an example of something unrelated?  Regular expression to match everything isn't going to be able to use any index effectively no matter what.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Terrible or nice, I don't know. Page 101 here: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do

Comment: We understand that you are working through the book (you have posted several questions that reference this), But the two points made here are highlighted in my answer (last point) that the first part of the explain output reflects the "match everything" nature of the query given. The answer further explains why there is this particular form used for "regex" operations. If you really have questions, then ask them on the answer. But the explanation should be very clear. Try to be "nice" to Asya. She is one of MongoDB's "gun" troubleshooters. You might need her someday.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sure, Neil. Thank you. I didn't know that I left the impression I intend to be not nice to someone :)

Comment: And yes... I am trying to read the book in details, I'll see if I'll manage it. I've posted quite some errata items too and I hope others could benefit from that. http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920028031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output there is particular to a regex that is not bound to the starting position of the string. So for a regex that is going to scan the index and not the collection (even though it will scan the whole index in this case) there needs to be a set of starting bounds and ending bounds:

Consider the first query with a different regex:

```js
db.collection.find({ "username": /bob/ }).explain()

    "indexBounds" : {
            "username" : [
                    [
                            "",
                            {

                            }
                    ],
                    [
                            /bob/,
                            /bob/
                    ]
            ]
    },
```

So that signifies there is a the whole string to search through and then the match will end on something that contains "bob" as part of the string. So the first part is the "lexical" match bounds and the second part is the actual regex to be applied:

The following query shows this more clearly:

```js
db.collection.find({ username: /^bob/ }).explain()

    "indexBounds" : {
            "username" : [
                    [
                            "bob",
                            "boc"
                    ],
                    [
                            /^bob/,
                            /^bob/
                    ]
            ]
    },
```

Since that is anchored to the start of the string, the only entries of the index that need to be tested match "lexically" between "bob" and "boc". The regex is again contained as the second part of the bounds.

The bounds entries are generally described as "two part" elements internally, and there is this case for regular expressions, which in the first part has the string bounds which makes sense for matching the index, and then for the regex to apply to those matching entires.

As a final note then see the following:

```js
db.collection.find({ username: {$gt: ""} }).explain()

    "indexBounds" : {
            "username" : [
                    [
                            "",
                            {

                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
```

Which is intrinsically the same as your initial query, that says to match **any** string.

Comment: Neil, I accepted your answer. I read it 2 times the other day, didn't quite get it. I will read it in some details when I have some more time. Thanks.

Comment: @peter.petrov Not too sure which part you "don not get". The various examples are very clear. 1.) A regex query will force a second "bounds" on the index condtions. Those are the regex terms, duplicated because that is that nature of the struct used. 2.) An open "match anything in the string" condition has a "bounds" condition of anything that **is** as string to something that **is not** a string (aka Object). All of those are clearly shown. You still have not awarded the bounty on this. If it is your first time, I can say, you don't get the points back. So that would be a waste :)

Comment: Should I award the bounty? I thought when I mark this as the right answer those points will be transferred to you. Let me check.