# How do I make a Case Insensitive, Partial Text Search Engine that uses Regex with MongoDB and PHP?

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, search-engine, case-insensitive

I'm trying to improve the search bar in my application. If a user types "Titan" into the search bar right now, the application will retrieve the movie "Titanic" from MongoDB every time I use the following regex function:

```
require 'dbconnection.php';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $input= $_REQUEST['input'];
$query=$collection->find(['movie' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($input)]);
}
```

I can also make collections case insensitive by creating the following index within the Mongo shell, so if a user types "tiTAnIc" into the search bar, the application will retrieve the movie "Titanic" from MongoDB:

```
db.createCollection("c1", { collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 } } )
db.c1.createIndex( { movie: 1 } )
```

I am not capable of combining these two features at the same time, however. The index above will only remove case sensitivity when I change my query to this:

```
$query=$collection->find( [ 'movie' => $input] );
```

If I use the regex query at the top in tandem with the collated index, it will ignore the regex part, so if I type "Titan," it doesn't retrieve anything; if I type "Titanic," however, it will successfully retrieve "Titanic" (because "Titanic" is the exact word stored in my database).

Any advice?

Comment: Use text search instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Beware:** Regex search on indexed column will affect the performance, as stated at [$regex docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

> Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.

Your problem is that MongoDB use *prefix* (ex: `/^acme/`) on `$regex` to lookup index.

> For case sensitive regular expression queries, if an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall within that range.

So it needs to be changed like this:

```
$query=$collection->find(['movie' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^'.$input, 'i')]);
```

I suggest you design your collection more carefully.

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228114/6118551
- https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-regular-expressions-indexes-performance/